# What if instead of Rf, there is use of grounding in Op-Amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I was studying for an exam the last night, but I couldn't get my head around this problem. What do I do here? Do I take as zero or something? The question is: what is the solution of the end of the 3rd Op-Amp?

[image]

Comment: The transistor is not a resistor and it’s not shorting the feedback to ground. I suggest you simulate this circuit to get a feel for what’s going on. Then you can replace the transistor with something simpler like a voltage source with a series resistor for example - at the particular operating point the circuit will operate at.

Comment: What does *"what is the solution of the end of the 3rd Op-Amp?"* mean?? What does `solution` mean here? What does `end of` mean? With regard to what? Why did you circle the BJT? Do you not understand what it is doing? And I think I see you cut a small rectangle out of the image. Why?

Comment: Fatih, Just as a start, look up 'log-amp' in order to deal with the red-circle. Then help us help you. Or not.